# Are ReadableByteChannel and WritableByteChannel a replacement of InputStream and OutputStream?

Tags: java, io, nio

As far as I know, `ReadableByteChannel` and `WritableByteChannel` from the `nio` package can be considered a replacement of `InputStream` and `OutputStream` from the legacy `io` package. If fact, they can be used to do the same I/O operations and more.

Nevertheless, they still seem not much used. Also, their support in popular libraries is quite poor. For example, the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) team is even [thinking about dropping it](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1180).

Is there any reason for new code dealing with I/O to use Streams with respect to Channels?

Comment: They must be kidding. You can't just remove things from shipped products.

Comment: Hahaha :) Guava developers know nothing about performance. Channels more performanet then streams...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a historical context that should not be ignored. When NIO was introduced (back in Java 1.4), a lot of features were missing and the promise to hand them in later was not hold for a long time. Recall that in Java 1.4 the way to get a `FileChannel` was to first create a `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, or `RandomAccessFile` and invoke `getChannel` on it. Thus, there was no way to write code using NIO/channels without using the older IO/stream API.

The first Java version providing a way to [create a `FileChannel` without using the old API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) is *Java 7*. This is also the first version providing an NIO API for directory scan, change notifications and advanced file attributes.

So the NIO API can be considered quite new regarding these features and it’s not that surprising that it takes some time for developers adopting it. By the way, this kind of adoption might include removing utility methods which became unnecessary with the new API like the proposal you have linked. As far as I can see it really means removing just four methods whose functionality is trivial when using the most recent API.

Obviously, when you want to use one of the newer features like memory mapping or the Java 7 features named above you have to use the NIO API. On the other hand, when you want to use Serialization or Zip/GZip (de)compression the only channel support, Java offers, is to wrap your channel into a stream…

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are doing. If you are dealing directly with files and/or sockets, there are many advantages to using `nio`. In some cases (especially around sockets) new functionality is /only/ being exposed through `nio`. Some of those advantages are muted if you also compress or encrypt data, where most apis only support streams. Historically the servlet-api spec was all based on streams. However, there is growing support for `nio` in that space as well.

Comment: So the only reason for using Streams seems to be compatibility with legacy code, but this can be achieved via the `Channels` utility class, am I right?

Comment: It can, which is why I indicated that the advantages are muted, not lost. What should be avoided, however, is moving back and forth between Channels and Streams multiple times for the same source of data.

Comment: @BrettOkken why?

Answer (score 0):

Immediate performance benefits are gained by using NIO Channels with [ByteBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Also if you need to block on multiple things [Selectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) can be handy.